# In redux combineReducers is it correct that all reducers are called?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 2 reducers (count and search) which I have combined. When the search component dispatches both reducers are called.

1. Is this expected behavior that all reducers are called?
2. Or, should only the most specific reducer (i.e. search) be called? What must I do to get only the most specific reducer to be called?

Here are the search, count and combined reducers

```
const initialState = {url:'...'};
function search(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'SEARCH') {
    ...
    return state;
  }
  return state;
}
export default search;
```

.

```
const initialState = 0;
function count(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'INCREMENT') {
    return state + 1;
  }
  if (action.type === 'DECREMENT') {
    return state - 1;
  }
  return state;
}
export default count;
```

.

```
import CountReducer from './CountReducer.js';
import SearchReducer from './ApiReducer.js';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const reduce = combineReducers({
  count: CountReducer,
  search: SearchReducer
});
export default reduce;
```

The search component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { onSearch as onSearchAction } from '../store/actions/Actions.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      ....
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { url: state.url };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return { onSearch: () => dispatch(onSearchAction()) };
};

const ConnectedSearch = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);

export default ConnectedSearch;
```

And here the search action

```
export function onSearch() {
  return {
    type: "SEARCH",
    url: '...'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior that all reducers are called?

Yes.

> What must I do to get only the most specific reducer to be called?

Well, you can write a custom reducer to do that, but i'm not sure what the benefit is. Presumably you would write code that says "if it's this action, or this action, or this action then call reducer 1; otherwise call reducer 2". But checking the action types is what reducer 1 **already does** so you're just duplicating the logic. Why not just call both reducers, and let them handle or ignore whatever they care or don't care about?

Comment: It can be a problem for larger apps, because in this case, all action types must be different in each reducer, otherwise you could have an unexpected behavior.